# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__' for Google Search

Tags: python

I have a list of people and companies and am trying to search Google to find out the linkedin urls for these folks.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import json
import urllib2
import time

file = open('names_and_companies.txt', 'r')
lines =file.readlines()
file.close()

file_out = open('out-urls.txt', 'w')

for line in lines:
    line = line.strip()
    lst = line.split(",")
    search_term = lst[0] + " " + lst[1] #construct a search term using name and company
    search_term = search_term.replace(" ","+")

    time.sleep(1)
    encoded = urllib2.quote(search_term)
    rawData = urllib2.urlopen ('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q='+encoded).read()

    jsonData = json.loads(rawData)
    print "\n\n\n" + search_term + "\n\n\n"


    searchResults = jsonData['responseData']['results']
    print searchResults

    for er in searchResults:
        link = er['url']
        if "www.linkedin.com" in link:
            print link
            file_out.write(lst[0] + " | " + lst[1] + " | " + link + "\n")

file_out.close()
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/InNov8/Desktop/conference/delete.py", line 30, in 
    searchResults = jsonData['responseData']['results']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

I know this topic has been covered before, however I'm a noob and can't figure out how to apply any of the recommended fixes to my specific code.

Thank you.

Comment: Try doing `print(jsonData['responseData'])`. See what it writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jsonData['responseData'] is returning None, so you can't index it (jsonData['responseData']['results'])

One possible workaround is to check if jsonData['responseData'] is None or not:

```
responseData = jsonData['responseData']
if responseData is not None: 
    searchResults = responseData['results']
    print searchResults

    for er in searchResults:
        link = er['url']
        if "www.linkedin.com" in link:
            print link
            file_out.write(lst[0] + " | " + lst[1] + " | " + link + "\n")
```